# Error installing Karma on Windows

Tags: node.js, karma-runner

I'm fairly new with nodejs, and I'm trying to install Karma. I would like to know how to solve this.

I'm getting an error when running this command :

```
c:\Apps\nodejs\ npm install karma
```

I have installed karma-cli successfully but when I try installing karma, I get the following error messages:

```
    C:\Apps\nodejs>npm install karma
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.8
\


> utf-8-validate@1.1.0 install C:\Apps\nodejs\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modu
les\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild

|
C:\Apps\nodejs\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-valid
ate>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Apps\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-
gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
Génération des projets individuellement dans cette solution. Pour activer la génération en parallèle, ajoutez le commuta
teur "/m".
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Impossible de charger le composant Visual C++ "VCBuild.exe". Pour corriger le problème, vous d
evez 1) installer le Kit de développement .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) installer Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 ou 3) ajout
er l'emplacement du composant au chemin d'accès système, s'il est installé ailleurs.  [C:\Apps\nodejs\node_modules\karm
a\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate\build\binding.sln]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Apps\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Apps\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Apps\nodejs\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_module
s\utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok

> bufferutil@1.1.0 install C:\Apps\nodejs\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\
ws\node_modules\bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Apps\nodejs\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil>
if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Apps\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\
bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
Génération des projets individuellement dans cette solution. Pour activer la génération en parallèle, ajoutez le commuta
teur "/m".
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Impossible de charger le composant Visual C++ "VCBuild.exe". Pour corriger le problème, vous d
evez 1) installer le Kit de développement .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) installer Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 ou 3) ajout
er l'emplacement du composant au chemin d'accès système, s'il est installé ailleurs.  [C:\Apps\nodejs\node_modules\karm
a\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\build\binding.sln]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Apps\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Apps\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Apps\nodejs\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_module
s\bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing utf-8-validate@1.1.0

> bufferutil@1.1.0 install C:\Apps\nodejs\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_m
odules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Apps\nodejs\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\nod
e_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Apps\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-
gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
Génération des projets individuellement dans cette solution. Pour activer la génération en parallèle, ajoutez le commuta
teur "/m".
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Impossible de charger le composant Visual C++ "VCBuild.exe". Pour corriger le problème, vous d
evez 1) installer le Kit de développement .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) installer Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 ou 3) ajout
er l'emplacement du composant au chemin d'accès système, s'il est installé ailleurs.  [C:\Apps\nodejs\node_modules\karm
a\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\buffe
rutil\build\binding.sln]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Apps\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Apps\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Apps\nodejs\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.
io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing bufferutil@1.1.0

> utf-8-validate@1.1.0 install C:\Apps\nodejs\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\no
de_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Apps\nodejs\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\nod
e_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Apps\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\n
ode-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
Génération des projets individuellement dans cette solution. Pour activer la génération en parallèle, ajoutez le commuta
teur "/m".
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Impossible de charger le composant Visual C++ "VCBuild.exe". Pour corriger le problème, vous d
evez 1) installer le Kit de développement .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) installer Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 ou 3) ajout
er l'emplacement du composant au chemin d'accès système, s'il est installé ailleurs.  [C:\Apps\nodejs\node_modules\karm
a\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8
-validate\build\binding.sln]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Apps\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Apps\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Apps\nodejs\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.
io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing bufferutil@1.1.0
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing utf-8-validate@1.1.0
karma@0.13.9 node_modules\karma
├── di@0.0.1
├── graceful-fs@4.1.2
├── rimraf@2.4.3
├── mime@1.3.4
├── colors@1.1.2
├── http-proxy@1.11.2 (eventemitter3@1.1.1, requires-port@0.0.1)
├── source-map@0.4.4 (amdefine@1.0.0)
├── useragent@2.1.7 (lru-cache@2.2.4)
├── optimist@0.6.1 (wordwrap@0.0.3, minimist@0.0.10)
├── bluebird@2.9.34
├── dom-serialize@2.2.0 (void-elements@1.0.0, custom-event@1.0.0, extend@2.0.1, ent@2.2.0)
├── glob@5.0.14 (path-is-absolute@1.0.0, inherits@2.0.1, inflight@1.0.4, once@1.3.2)
├── minimatch@2.0.10 (brace-expansion@1.1.0)
├── connect@3.4.0 (utils-merge@1.0.0, parseurl@1.3.0, debug@2.2.0, finalhandler@0.4.0)
├── body-parser@1.13.3 (bytes@2.1.0, content-type@1.0.1, depd@1.0.1, qs@4.0.0, on-finished@2.3.0, http-errors@1.3.1, raw
-body@2.1.2, debug@2.2.0, iconv-lite@0.4.11, type-is@1.6.7)
├── expand-braces@0.1.1 (array-uniq@1.0.2, array-slice@0.2.3, braces@0.1.5)
├── lodash@3.10.1
├── chokidar@1.0.5 (arrify@1.0.0, path-is-absolute@1.0.0, is-glob@1.1.3, glob-parent@1.2.0, async-each@0.1.6, is-binary-
path@1.0.1, readdirp@1.4.0, anymatch@1.3.0)
├── memoizee@0.3.9 (lru-queue@0.1.0, next-tick@0.2.2, timers-ext@0.1.0, d@0.1.1, event-emitter@0.3.3, es6-weak-map@0.1.4
, es5-ext@0.10.7)
├── log4js@0.6.26 (async@0.2.10, underscore@1.8.2, readable-stream@1.0.33, semver@4.3.6)
├── core-js@1.1.3
└── socket.io@1.3.6 (debug@2.1.0, has-binary-data@0.1.3, socket.io-adapter@0.3.1, socket.io-parser@2.2.4, engine.io@1.5.
2, socket.io-client@1.3.6)

C:\Apps\nodejs>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a C++ compiler. The module node-gyp require it. Install [Visual Studio Express](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs) then run the install again.